# cURL timeout with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently working with `PHP / cURL` to send files to my API. I used Postman and the result was successful. Then, I used the Postman code generator to get my `cURL` request, but when I put this in my `PHP` page, the return is

> cURL Error #:Operation timed out after 100000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received".

I looked on many different forums but I didn't found any operational solution. (The code has been automatically generated by Postman, this solution worked for others parts of the API like register, login...)

Can someone help me about this please?

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "3000",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://XXXXXXXXXX:3000/api/StorageAgent/uploadFile",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"path_ftp\"\r\n\r\n./\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\\uploads\\2.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: 9e868801-b05e-4161-9d94-63b52e6f7b28",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhN2RhNjE3N2M0Mzg5MjliYmQ0OWI4OSIsImFkbWluIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNTIzNDUxMzUxLCJleHAiOjE1MjM1Mzc3NTF9.jljyezECyjI0Z-RM-CttjSnYHh56rJdxzZJGh-TtwgQ"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  var_dump("nop");
} else {
  echo $response;
  var_dump("yep");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried without this line: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100,` ? I know that 100 seconds is a lot of time, but if You try to send big file with slow connection it could get timeout.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I know, but what is not understable for me, that without 50 reputation points I can't write comments :|

Comment: When i try this, i got PHP error :

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www\4pjt\test.php

I think that's strange to get "0 bytes received" no ? I try to send a simple image of 2.02Ko

Answer (score 0):

Please remove any content-length param, postman-token, cookie param generated by Postman  code generator as it is specific to the request you made via potsman. Doing this should allow your input to work as its own specific request.

Remove

```
"Postman-Token: 9e868801-b05e-4161-9d94-63b52e6f7b28",
```